# Resetting RadioGroup value in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui, radio-group

I am attempting to build a quiz app using React. I am using Material-UI for radio button input for multi-choice questions, and am having issues clearing the selected buttons when a new questions loads. For instance, on question 1 if the user selects answer A, when they move on the next question A is selected by default.

I have tried resetting `this.state.value` to undefined and null after a response is submitted, tried making separate state for each question to use as the starting value, etc. Nothing works. From examining the React components via developer tools I can see the value within the RadioGroup being reset to null or undefined, but Hook shows the prior answer is maintained from the question before. I can't figure out how to reset.

Here are my handlers/state:

```
  this.state = {
      q_number: 1,
      value: undefined
    };

    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleNext = () => {
    var new_index = this.state.q_number; 
    this.setState({ q_number: new_index + 1, value: undefined});
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value }); 
  };
```

Example form with two questions:

```
render() {
   let content; 
   if (this.state.q_number === 1) {
        content = (
            <div>
                <FormControl className="answers-form" component="fieldset">
                    <RadioGroup name="questions1" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <FormControlLabel value="a" control={<Radio color="default"/>} label="Answer 1" />
                        <FormControlLabel value="b" control={<Radio color="default"/>} label="Answer 2" />
                 
                    </RadioGroup>
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        ); 
    } else if(this.state.q_number === 2) {
        content = (
            <div>
             
                <FormControl className="answers-form" component="fieldset">
                    <RadioGroup name="questions2" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <FormControlLabel value="a" control={<Radio color="default"/>} label="Answer 1" />
                        <FormControlLabel value="b" control={<Radio color="default"/>} label="Answer 2" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        );
    }

 return (
        <div className="body questions">
            <div>
                {content}
                <Button className={btnClass} color="primary" onClick = {() =>this.handleNext()}>
                    Next
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not seeing increment_q function, but what you want to achieve is the basic state case.

Do something like this:

```
<Button className={btnClass} color="primary" onClick={this.incrementNextValue} />

incrementNextValue = () => {
  this.setState({q_number: this.state.q_number + 1});
}
```

The same works for the handleChange in the radio buttons.
Also, bind is not necessary if you are using arrow functions.

That will re-render your component, your state will be different and the correct next button should be displayed.

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo on the code which I corrected - increment_q should be handleNext(). Regardless, my issue hasnt been with getting the state to change to render teh next question, instead it has been to get the radio buttons to be unselected on the new question. In effect, it retains the last response from the prior RadioGroup...